# AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.unity.ads.UnityInterstitialAdCallback

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob

I added Admob into my game and my test ads works on unity editor perfectly and ı don't get any error. However when ı get build for my android device, Ads doesn't show and I get error for this line :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.unity.ads.UnityInterstitialAdCallback
java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.access$300(Unknown Source:0)
com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e$1.handleMessage(Unknown Source:95)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e.run(Unknown Source:20)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.unity.ads.UnityInterstitialAdCallback" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.tts.puzzle.brick.infinity-N5SeCpyddtonur1RZv9mHA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.tts.puzzle.brick.infinity-N5SeCpyddtonur1RZv9mHA==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.tts.puzzle.brick.infinity-N5SeCpyddtonur1RZv9mHA==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
... 8 more
UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CheckException () (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.FindClass (System.String name) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
UnityEngine.AndroidJavaClass._AndroidJavaClass (System.String className) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
UnityEngine.AndroidJavaProxy..ctor (System.String javaInterface) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
GoogleMobileAds.Android.InterstitialClient..ctor () (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
GoogleMobileAds.GoogleMobileAdsClientFactory.BuildInterstitialClient () (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
GoogleMobileAds.Api.InterstitialAd..ctor (System.String adUnitId) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
EasyMobile.AdMobClientImpl+Interstitial+Instance.Load () (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
EasyMobile.AdMobClientImpl+Interstitial.Load (EasyMobile.AdPlacement placement) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
EasyMobile.Advertising.LoadAllInterstitialAds (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] clients) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
EasyMobile.Advertising+<CRAutoLoadAllAds>d__143.MoveNext () (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, System.IntPtr returnValueAddress) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like there is a missing class in your build. Did you resolve all android dependencies? Check-in Assets -> Plugins -> Android folder for googlemobileads-unity.aar file. if this file is not there then do following.

Try to force resolve android dependency in Android Resolver -> Force Resolve. And it'll include all the files in your build.

Comment: Thanks for your response, googlemobileads-unity.aar file is there and already run this  force resolve android dependency many time.

Comment: what about proguard do you use it?

Comment: Yes Used that too..

Comment: Used proguard and added that code in it too.
 -keep class com.google.unity.** {
    *;
 }
 -keep public class com.google.android.gms.ads.**{
    public *;
 }
 -keep public class com.google.ads.**{
    public *;
 }

 -keepattributes *Annotation*
 -dontobfuscate

Comment: Test ads working fine in unity editor but not working in mobile, I used Lunar Console to get that error in Mobile..

Comment: Can you use this proguard  -keep class com.google.unity.** {
   *;
}
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.ads.**{
   public *;
}
-keep public class com.google.ads.**{
   public *;
}
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-dontobfuscate

Comment: As I already mentioned I used that code too..

Comment: There is difference in your proguard and mine

Comment: Oh, many thanks, bro! It super helped me!